# pytorch tensor change dimensionallity to count adjacent values

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

My objective it to count all adjacent unique values of a tensor `x`. 
Say my tensor is (`x` looks like a list but it is a pytorch tensor)

```
x = [1,2,1,2,4,5]
```

I would want my output to be:

```
[1,2] = 2
[2,1] = 1
[2,4] = 1
[4,5] = 1
```

I thought about changing the dimensionality of the tensor to look like:

```
x = [[1,2],[2,1],[1,2],[2,4],[4,5]]
```

using `tensor.view` but couldn't find a solution that works for a tensor of any length.
Any ideas if this is even the best way to go about this? is there some built-in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@ihdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11790637/ihdv) showed, you can stack shifted views of `x` with [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html) or [`torch.vstack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.vstack.html) in order to get a tensor of pairs with overlapping windows.

```
>>> p = torch.vstack((x[:-1], x[1:]))
tensor([[1., 2., 1., 2., 4.],
        [2., 1., 2., 4., 5.]])
```

Then you can apply [`torch.unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html#torch.unique) on it to get the statistics:

```
>>> p.unique(dim=1, return_counts=True)
(tensor([[1., 2., 2., 4.],
         [2., 1., 4., 5.]]), tensor([2, 1, 1, 1]))
```